# Can't access model class in second page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to access a model class in the second page of my app.

In the first which I have named Main Activity I am able to call the class and write an updated value to it. My class is as follows:

```
class UserDetails{

String userName = "";
String userSurname = "";
}
```

In `MainActivity` I am able to call the above and update the userName and userSurname after reading from Firestore and print in the console:

```
UserDetails details = UserDetails();

  details.userName = userName;
  details.userSurname = userSurname;

  print(details.userName);
  print(details.userSurname);
```

When I move to the second page and try to call the same first two lines shown below I cannot even autocomplete the `details.userName`.

```
 UserDetails details = UserDetails();

  details.userName = userName;
```

The package is imported on both MainActivity and the second page. any idea why I cannot get UserDetails in the second? I thought maybe it is not re-usable across pages but even if I remove it from MainActivity it still doesnt allow the usage on the second page.

Essentially what I am trying to do is use userName and userSurname as global variables.

Answer (score 0):

if the class is imported in both of your classes.

Run the command `flutter clean`. That would solve your problem.

I hope this helps.

Comment: can i actually use the same model after being updated to pull through the updated value in the second page? sought of like a global variiable?

Comment: You can do that but with the help of a state management technique like Provider.